# Is my proof for the sum of two square roots being irrational correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Prove that the following number is irrational:

$$\sqrt { 5 } +\sqrt { 3 } $$

Steps I took:

Proof by contradiction: let us assume that $\sqrt { 5 } +\sqrt { 3 } $ is rational.

If $\sqrt { 5 } +\sqrt { 3 } $ is rational, so is $(\sqrt { 5 } +\sqrt { 3 } )^{ 2 }$

$$(\sqrt { 5 } +\sqrt { 3 } )^{ 2 }=5+2\sqrt { 15 } +3= 2\sqrt { 15 } +8$$

However, this is a contradiction since $\sqrt { 15 } $ is irrational.

Is my proof good? What needs to be added and how can it be made more complete if it already isn't. Please note that I already proved that $\sqrt { 15 } $ is irrational in part (a) of the problem. This is part(b). That is why I didn't bother to prove it again. I guess you could say the irrationality of $\sqrt { 15 } $ was given when I started the proof.

Comment: your proof seems good.

Comment: A little mistake. You should replace the sign $\Rightarrow$ by $=$.

Comment: Your proof is correct but the method does not always work. What if you had to prove that $\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{2}$ is irrational? The square is $8+8+2=18$.

Comment: @user37238 better?

Comment: @uniquesolution what would you recommend?

Comment: @uniquesolution in that case his approach would work again: $\sqrt 8+\sqrt 2=3\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @Math-fun -- his approach was to square the number, not what you wrote.